# TURN server for WebRTC with REST API authentication

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, webrtc, turn

I'm trying to set up the rfc5766-turn-server TURN server for webRTC from [here](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/).
I was able to successfully relay my video through this TURN server using a `turnuserdb.conf` file where I have my username and password (my_user_name:my_password).
And on the web client side I used:

```
"iceServers":{[
    "url": "turn:my_user_name,@turn_server_ip",
    "credential":"my_password"
}]
```

I'm trying to use the REST API feature that comes with the TURN server to avoid sending the password over the network or storing it on the client side.
I followed [this spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-uberti-behave-turn-rest-00)  and [this explanation](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/wiki/turnserver) under the Rest API

However unfortunately I get a **401** and I cannot authenticate.

Here's what I did exactly:

1. I created a secret "my_secret" and I ran the turn server like this:

   ```
   turnserver -v --syslog -a -L xx.xxx.xx.xx -X yy.yyy.yyy.yy -E zz.zzz.zz.zzz --max-bps=3000000 -f -m 3 --min-port=32355 --max-port=65535 --use-auth-secret --static-auth-secret=my_secret --realm=north.gov --cert=turn_server_cert.pem --pkey=turn_server_pkey.pem --log-file=stdout -q 100 -Q 300 --cipher-list=ALL
   ```

   (I just replaced the IP address with `xx.xxx.xx.xx` `yy.yyy.yyy.yy` `zz.zzz.zz.zzz`)
2. Later I generated a timestamp that would be now + 1 hour so I ran on nodejs:

   ```
   Date.now()+1000*60*60;      // output 1433895918506.
   ```

   I generated the temporary password on [this website](http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html),
   Using my secret, and got a result `0ca57806bdc696b3129d4cad83746945b00af77b`
3. I encoded the password to *base64*.
4. Now I tried to log communicate with the turn server from the web client using the temporary username :  `1433895918506:my_user_name` and password: `MGNhNTc4MDZiZGM2OTZiMzEyOWQ0Y2FkODM3NDY5NDViMDBhZjc3Yg==`, on the web client now I use

   ```
   "iceServers":"url":"turn:1433895918506:my_user_name@turn_server_ip","credential":"MGNhNTc4MDZiZGM2OTZiMzEyOWQ0Y2FkODM3NDY5NDViMDBhZjc3Yg=="}]
   ```

But it doesn't work, I get:

```
401 user <1433895918506:my_user_name>  incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised.
```

Can you help me figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when I generated credential with your name and secret, I got **`1Dj9XZ5fwvKS6YoQZOoORcFnXaI=`** not `MGNhNTc4MDZiZGM2OTZiMzEyOWQ0Y2FkODM3NDY5NDViMDBhZjc3Yg==`, check your algorithm/code for errors.

and the time is in **Unix Timestamp**, so in seconds and not milliseconds as you did( though this should not affect, but just makes your credentials never expire)

check if your system and the system where the TURN server is running, the clocks are in sync( at least not days apart), and in general, to avoid issue of clocks not being in sync, better to use ttl as 24 hours, so your timestamp:

```
timestamp=  parseInt(Date.now()/1000) + 24*3600
```

the code for generating TURN credential:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function getTURNCredentials(name, secret){    

    var unixTimeStamp = parseInt(Date.now()/1000) + 24*3600,
        username = [unixTimeStamp, name].join(':'),
        password,
        hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret);
    hmac.setEncoding('base64');
    hmac.write(username);
    hmac.end();
    password = hmac.read();
    return {
        username: username,
        password: password
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes I had a bug in the conversion from hex to base64 and I missed the milliseconds to seconds conversion. Thank you for your help