# CoTURN: How to use TURN REST API?

Tags: rest, api, webrtc, turn, coturn

I have build coturn and run it successfully. ip:192.168.1.111. Now the question I faced is to get the Turn credential through REST API.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-uberti-behave-turn-rest-00 According to the passage the request format should be

`GET /?service=turn&username=mbzrxpgjys`

and response should be `JSON`. Now my question is:

a) How to configure and command TURN SERVER to make it run in `REST API` mode?

b) How to write a http request in the right format so `TURN SERVER` can reply correctly? could you give me an example?

Answer (score 73):

Few things to be clarified here are:

- `GET /?service=turn&username=mbzrxpgjys` which returns a JSON, is just a **suggested** uri for retrieving **time-limited** TURN credentials from the server, you do not have to follow that, your uri can be just `/?giveMeCredentials`. In fact, I use my socket connection to retrieve this data, not direct http call with json response. End of day, it does not matter how you( the client that uses said TURN) get those credentials as long as they are valid.
- You do not make any requests to the TURN server directly, **no rest api** call to TURN server is under your control.
- you allocate a secret key when you are starting the TURN server, this can be taken from a db(thus dynamically changable), but lazy that I am, just hard-coded, and gave it in the turn config file, also remember to enable REST API. As part of turn command, `turnserver ... --use-auth-secret --static-auth-secret=MySecretKey`
- Now, in your application server, you would use the same secret key to generate credentials, for username, it is UNIX timestamp and some string( can be random or user id or something) seperated by `:` and the password would be HMAC of the username with your secret key.
- about the UNIX timestamp, this has be the time in TURN server till which your credentials has to be valid, so which calculating this make sure you take into account of the clock time difference between your application server and your turn server.

Now some sample code taken from my answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30745153/3074768)

command for stating TURN server:

```sh
turnserver -v --syslog -a -L xx.xxx.xx.xx -X yy.yyy.yyy.yy -E zz.zzz.zz.zzz --max-bps=3000000 -f -m 3 --min-port=32355 --max-port=65535 --use-auth-secret --static-auth-secret=my_secret --realm=north.gov --cert=turn_server_cert.pem --pkey=turn_server_pkey.pem --log-file=stdout -q 100 -Q 300 --cipher-list=ALL
```

`node.js` code for creating TURN credentials in application server:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');

function getTURNCredentials(name, secret){    

    var unixTimeStamp = parseInt(Date.now()/1000) + 24*3600,   // this credential would be valid for the next 24 hours
        username = [unixTimeStamp, name].join(':'),
        password,
        hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret);
    hmac.setEncoding('base64');
    hmac.write(username);
    hmac.end();
    password = hmac.read();
    return {
        username: username,
        password: password
    };
}
```

Browser code for using this:

```js
  ...
  iceServers:[
    {
      urls: "turn:turn_server_ip",
      username: username,
      credential:password
    }
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that the timestamp is not the actual timestamp but the expiration timestamp, I forgot that. I also had to use the RAW output of HMAC, like @SparX said, otherwise I got this error: `489: session 001000000000000004: realm <> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
489: check_stun_auth: Cannot find credentials of user <1564836087:webrtc>`.
By the way, the end of the username `:randomText` is not needed, you can just use the timestamp, like I read in coturn config file.

Comment: If someone is looking for **C#** code: https://gist.github.com/robingenz/e47f42452d82fa9c1fa529b9ae3be95c

Comment: can anyone help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154550/getting-uncaught-domexception-failed-to-construct-rtcpeerconnection-username

Comment: I was pulling my hair out all day today trying this, just to find out somewhat randomly that in order for this to work, one *has* to also specify a realm. If the `realm` option is not set in the configuration, it doesn't work and one gets the `realm <> user <>` error messages. Maybe this can save someone some hair!

Answer (score 12):

After (many) hours of frustration, @Mido's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35767224/4447471) here was the only thing that actually got CoTurn's REST API working for me.

My credential server is PHP and I use CoTurn's config file 'turnserver.conf' so here's a tested and working translation of Mido's work for that situation:

Assuming a 'shared secret' of '3575819665154b268af59efedee8826e', here are the relevant turnserver.conf entries:

```
lt-cred-mech
use-auth-secret
static-auth-secret=3575819665154b268af59efedee8826e
```

...and the PHP (which misled me for ages):

```
$ttl = 24 * 3600;  // Time to live
$time = time() + $ttl;
$username = $time . ':' . $user;
$password = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $username, '3575819665154b268af59efedee8826e', true));
```

Comment: The secret hash you used in your answer reminded me that coturn says the secret should be hashed with MD5 but I tested without hashing the secret and it worked too. Is there an advantage of using a hashed secret? I guess using a secret that is not hashed is secure enough.
I also noticed that the configuration entries `lt-cred-mech` and `use-auth-secret` are not needed. You just have to use `static-auth-secret` (and `cert` + `pkey` to use an SSL certificate). In the WebRTC JavaScript code, the port 5349 should be used for secure connection, otherwise it uses unencrypted port 3478.

Comment: @baptx The only reason I use a secret which is a hash of something, is to make it easy to automate changing it, while being pretty impossible to guess or brute force. I also own only so many cats, so run out of cat-name-passwords pretty quickly.

Answer (score 8):

Building upon @Mido and @HeyHeyJC answers, here is the Python implementation to build credentials for coturn.

```python
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
from time import time

user = 'your-arbitrary-username'
secret = 'this-is-the-secret-configured-for-coturn-server'

ttl = 24 * 3600 # Time to live
timestamp = int(time()) + ttl
username = str(timestamp) + ':' + user
dig = hmac.new(secret.encode(), username.encode(), hashlib.sha1).digest()
password = base64.b64encode(dig).decode()

print('username: %s' % username)
print('password: %s' % password)
```

Here is a [web application](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) to test the login to your coturn server. Use `turn:host.example.com` as the server name.

Comment: I had to use `bytes(secret, 'utf-8')` and `bytes(username, 'utf-8')` (Python3.9)

Answer (score 4):

I came across similar issue (getting REST API working with TURN server) recently and learned that TURN server doesn't support REST API calls at all and just provides support for an authentication format with shared secret when we enable REST API support in TURN config. The [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-uberti-behave-turn-rest-00) only provides info on things that we need to consider while implementing such REST API and WE need to create the API on our own or use something like [turnhttp](https://github.com/dataarts/turnhttp) to generate the temporary username password combo.

As @mido detailed, you can implement the username/password generation part in the application itself. But if you have reasons to separate this from the application and want to implement it as an entirely different API service, instead of implementing a complete API as per the [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-uberti-behave-turn-rest-00), I came across another [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/turn-server-project-rfc5766-turn-server/xUm962OG3m4) in which the OP provided a PHP script to generate temp username & password and this one works pretty well once you modify the hash_hmac() function to the following,

```
$turn_password = hash_hmac('sha1', $turn_user, $secret_key, true);
```

We need to base64 encode the RAW output of **hash_hmac** to get it working and I believe this is why it was not working for the OP in that link.

You should be able to test authentication using **turnutils_uclient** command to verify that the temp username/password combo is working as expected.

```
turnutils_uclient -y -u GENERATED_USERNAME -w GENERATED_PASSWORD yourturnserver.com
```

Once you have verified authentication and confirmed that it's working, you can setup webserver for the PHP script to make it available to your application and fetch the temporary username/password combo. Also, you would need to implement other security setup (authentication) to protect the API from unauthorized access.

I know this is an old post, just sharing my findings here hoping that it will be useful for someone someday.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that we have to use the RAW output, it helped me to get it working. But if people read this, I would recommend to do a real test (e.g. with WebRTC) even if the `turnutils_uclient` command fails with `0: error 401 (Unauthorized)`. It my case the command failed but WebRTC worked when I forced Firefox to use a TURN server, maybe you have an idea why? I tested the command on the Linux server where the TURN server is installed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my c# implementation with TTL

```
public string[] GenerateTurnPassword(string username)
{
    long ttl = 3600 * 6;
    var time = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds() + ttl;
    var newuser = time + ":" + username;
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("YOURSECRET");
    HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(key);
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newuser);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    var hashValue = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(stream);
    string[] arr = new string[2];
    arr[0] = Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);
    arr[1] = newuser;
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well @Augusto Destrero provided implementation will cause `TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'` on Python 3.7.6, for anyone looking for another Python implementation, here is an example:

```py
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

secret = b'abcdefghijkmln'

def generateTurnUsernamePwd():
    username = "arbitry username here"
    password = hmac.new(secret, bytes(username, 'UTF-8'), hashlib.sha1).digest()
    passwordStr = base64.b64encode(password).decode("utf-8")
    
    return username,passwordStr

print(generateTurnUsernamePwd())
```

The main difference is `key` and `message` keyword arguments in `hmac` lib has to be bytes in newer version , while in older versions, it requires str.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it worthwhile to add to the answer the actual text of the documentation of coturn regardingg this topic and a [link](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/commit/708b83ea78dfe109d1ddf5565660da957d155eff#) to it for those interested:

> --auth-secret TURN REST API flag.             Flag that sets a special WebRTC authorization option            that is based upon authentication secret. The
> feature purpose           is to support "TURN Server REST API" as described
> in            the TURN REST API section below.            This option uses timestamp
> as part of combined username:             usercombo -> "timestamp:username",
> turn user -> usercombo,             turn password ->
> base64(hmac(input_buffer = usercombo, key = shared-secret)).          This
> allows TURN credentials to be accounted for a specific user id.           If
> you don't have a suitable id, the timestamp alone can be used.            This
> option is just turns on secret-based authentication.          The actual
> value of the secret is defined either by option static-auth-secret,
> or can be found in the turn_secret table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for go with ttl:

```go
import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const turnTokenTtl = time.Hour * 24
const turnSecret = "your secret"

func getTurnCredentials(name string) (string, string) {
    timestamp := time.Now().Add(turnTokenTtl).Unix()
    username := fmt.Sprintf("%d:%s", timestamp, name)
    h := hmac.New(sha1.New, []byte(turnSecret))
    h.Write([]byte(username))
    credential := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
    return username, credential
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found in bash (simply replace `<static-auth-secret>` with your own Turn secret) :

```bash
turn_secret=<static-auth-secret>
current_timestamp=$(date +%s)
future_timestamp=$((current_timestamp + 86400))
username="${future_timestamp}:foo"
password=$(echo -n "$username" | openssl sha1 -hmac "$turn_secret" -binary | base64)
echo $username
echo $password
```

You can then use username and password as your credentials.

What it does :

- Compute a Unix timestamp (`date +%s`,[number of seconds since January 1st 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))
- Add 86400 seconds (one day) for end of validity
- Create username with : timestamp + ":" + foo ("foo" could be replaced by anything !)
- Compute a HMAC-SHA1 hash of username and Turn secret (`openssl sha1...`)
- Convert from binary (ASCII) to base64

You can test your username and password on [Trickle Ice](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/)

[This page](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/administration/turn-server/#test-your-turn-server) from the BigBlueButton project also give hints on how you can test your own Turn server