# coturn cannot find credentials of user

Tags: turn, coturn

I was trying to deploy a simple TURN server using **coturn**. 
When I test it on [Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) (`turn:rtc.jackxujh.me:3478 [webrtc:mighty]`), Trickle ICE says *"Authentication failed?"*. 
The *coturn* server keeps reporting this error:

> ERROR: check_stun_auth: Cannot find credentials of user

[image: Trickle ICE shows Authentication failure.]

---

Here is the complete `turnserver.conf` I am using (by uncommenting lines of the *coturn* sample conf):

```
external-ip=39.108.74.114/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX #(XXX is internal IP)
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech
use-auth-secret
static-auth-secret=XXXXXXXX... #(XXX is the secret)
realm=rtc.jackxujh.me
user=webrtc:0xXXXXXXXX... #(XXX is the key)
cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/rtc.jackxujh.me/cert.pem
pkey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/rtc.jackxujh.me/privkey.pem
mobility
```

I find a related discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/issues/1915), but I don't feel there is a solution at the end.

**In fact, I am confused whether my conf file is using TURN REST API or not.**

Meanwhile, I tried to check if there was a user named *webrtc* in *turndb*, by using `# turnadmin -l`, but the output was nothing. (Is this command correct?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CoTURN: How to use TURN REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766382/coturn-how-to-use-turn-rest-api)

Answer (score 1):

> **In fact, I am confused whether my conf file is using TURN REST API or not.**

I can confirm You use REST API because use-auth-secret is set

```
use-auth-secret
```

So you need to use a unixtimestamp as username, and the hashed password..

```
user=timestamp:userid
password=base64(hmac(secret key, user)
```

Read more about the difference of Long-Term-Credential and REST:

https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/87/slides/slides-87-behave-10.pdf

If you want to use normal username/password use the long-term-credential so remove use-auth-secret

and set it statically or in db

```
user=username1:key1
```

> **turnadmin**

`turnadmin -l`

list static and db users.

So in case of REST is correct the empty list.