# WebRTC using static-auth-secret for oauth credential type

Tags: oauth, webrtc

My server is configured to use a `static-auth-secret` so I changed the WebRTC Trickle ICE example to use `oauth` as the credential type, and I hoped this would allow me to use the static-auth-secret for authentication.

However, I get this error now:

```
TypeError: RTCPeerConnection constructor: 'oauth' (value of 'credentialType' member of RTCIceServer) is not a valid value for enumeration RTCIceCredentialType.
```

This is what my iceServer object looks like now:

```
 const iceServer = {
    urls: [urlInput.value],
    credential: passcodeInput.value,
    credentialType: 'oauth'
  };
```

This doesn't make sense because the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer/credentialType) says credentialType can be either oauth or password.

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth credential type [was removed from the WebRTC 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2019/CR-webrtc-20191213/#sotd) for lack of implementation in browsers.

It may come back later as an [extension to WebRTC 1.0](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-extensions/#rtcoauthcredential-dictionary).

At the moment, it is not possible to authenticate with OAuth to an ICE server in deployed browser implementations of WebRTC. See the relevant browser bugs:

- [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1247616)
- [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4907)

Answer (score 0):

As @dontcallmedom mentions, oauth is not supported. So, to solve my problem of authenticating with a server using a passcode, I had to develop a Node.js Express API which generated ephemeral credentials that worked for default `password` ICE server authentication. Big note: this REST API is not provided by default, it is made by the user.

More detailed instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766382/coturn-how-to-use-turn-rest-api)