# CoTurn Data Usage Stats on Multi User System

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

We want to track each users turn usage seperately. I inspected Turn Rest API, AFAIU it is just used to authorize the user which already exists in Coturn db. This is the point I couldn't realize exactly. I can use an ice server list which includes different username-credential peers. But I must have initialized these username-credential peers on coturn db before. Am I right? If I am right, I do not have an idea how to do this. Detection of user's request to use turn from frontend -> Should generate credentials like this [CoTURN: How to use TURN REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766382/coturn-how-to-use-turn-rest-api) which I am already achieved -> if this is a new user, my backend should go to my EC2 instance and run "turnadmin create user command" somehow -> then I will let the WebRTC connection - > then track the usage of specific user and send it back to my backend somehow.

Is this a true scenario? If not, how should it be? Is there another way to manage multiple users and their data usage? Any help would be appreciated.

AFAIU to get the stats data, we must use redis database. I tried to used it, I displayed the traffic data (with psubscribe turn/realm/*/user/*/allocation/*/traffic ) but the other subscribe events have never worked ( psubscribe turn/realm/*/user/*/allocation/*/traffic/peer or psubscribe turn/realm/*/user/*/allocation/*/total_traffic even if the allocation is deleted). So, I tried to get past traffic data from redis db but I couldn't find how. At redis, KEYS * command gives just "status" events.

Even if I get these traffic data, I couldn't realize how to use it with multi users. Currently in our project we have one user(in terms of coturn) and other users are using turn over this user.

BTW we tried to track the usage where we created peer connection object from RTCPeerConnection interface. I realized that incoming bytes are lower than the redis output. So I think there is a loss and I think I should calculate it from turn side.

Comment: We also want to know in our application that which user is usingTURN and which not, Any success on this ?

Comment: Using REST API allowed us to distinguish users. While we are creating credentials, we give specific id for username field. So, in the metrics of CoTurn we can see the usages of each user. Still we could not record usages consistently.